# Eclipse C++ "#include" and "using namespace" errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, namespaces, include, mingw

My aunt gave me a book about c++ (for beginners). It's nice and so I wanted to test one of those code samples. But I am just getting errors. I didn't find anything that could help me on Google or so.
I am using Eclipse Mars.1 C++ and MinGW.

Code:

```
    /*
 * Erstes_Programm.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 26.12.2015
 *      Author: Luca
 */

// Erstes Programm
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "It's just a test!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting those errors:

Using namespace:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type    
expected ';' before ':' token   
Erstes_Programm.cpp /Programmieren C++ (Einführung)    
line 10    
C/C++ Problem
```

AND

```
Description Resource Path Location Type   
expected unqualified-id before ':' token    
Erstes_Programm.cpp /Programmieren C++ (Einführung)   
line 10  
C/C++ Problem
```

Hope somebody can help me?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screen shot of code]

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED!! I don't know WHAT I did, but it's solved I'm not getting any errors and everything works perfectly. Thanks for everybody who wanted to help

Comment: Your issue is probably a faulty compiler because the code looks fine.

Comment: Did you save the code?

Comment: I don't think that source code could give you those error messages.

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code direct into your question please (and format it as code with the {} button on the toolbar).  I don't believe it is a faulty compiler though (although it *might* be compiler configuration)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I fixed the link, so it is an image now. The other thing that I fixed was the errors that you posted, they should be formatted as code, this makes them easier to read. The screen shot is good, only you should also post your code as a code block, this allows copy/paste, and makes it easier to read. Other then that, great job on your post!

Comment: @MartinBonner I posted the Code...What do you think I have to do to fix it(You said it might be the compiler configuration)??

Answer (score 0):

The first line in the screenshot doesn't make any sense. Remove it. The rest looks fine. And in the future, post **text**, not screenshots.

Comment: The first line is obviously a collapsed comment (look at the line numbers, and the '+' next to line 2).  Don't think this is the OP's problem.  (Strongly agree about text though).

Comment: @MartinBonner - <shrug>. It's the code that was posted. If the actual problem is with some other code, then that should be posted. Guessing what might be hidden somewhere is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead work on X-code rather then eclipse for C++. Visual studio is most recommend.
For Your problem, I think you got to play with the library, something must not be supported, other then that your code look fine.